# Exercise from thinking in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to do this:

> Create a base class containing a clone( ) function that returns a
>   pointer to a copy of the current object. Derive two subclasses that
>   override clone( ) to return copies of their specific types. In main(
>   ), create and upcast objects of your two derived types, then call
>   clone( ) for each and verify that the cloned copies are the correct
>   subtypes. Experiment with your clone( ) function so that you return
>   the base type, then try returning the exact derived type. Can you
>   think of situations in which the latter approach is necessary?

My attempt:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:

    virtual Base* clone() {
        Base copy = *this;
        return &copy;
    }

    void show() {
        cout << "BASE\n";

    }

};

class D1 : public Base {
public:

    Base* clone() {
        cout << "OVEr\n";

        D1 copy = *this;
        D1* clo = dynamic_cast<D1*> (&copy);

        return clo;
    }

    void show() {
        cout << "D1\n";

    }

};



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    D1 d1;

    Base& ptr1 = d1;
    (ptr1.clone())->show();

    return 0;
}
```

What is my problem? I can't imagine how to return D1* object if we should override virtual Base* clone().

Comment: `Base copy = *this; return &copy;` - you're returning the address of a local variable. This is most definitely **not** what you want.

Comment: `show()` should probably by `virtual`, too.

Comment: (1) the exercise says you need two subclasses. (2) Implementing `clone` without using `new` is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code here:

```
virtual Base* clone() {
    Base copy = *this;
    return &copy;
}
```

does not do you want it to.  This returns the address of a local variable that falls out of scope after the closing `}`.  What you need to do is dynamically allocate the clone with the `new` keyword:

```
virtual Base* clone() {
    Base* copy = new Base(*this); // NOTE: This calls a copy constructor
    return copy;
}
```

If you dynamically allocate objects with `new`, you must also remember to deallocate them with `delete`, or else you'll create a memory leak.

To override the clone function, you should use the `override` keyword to catch mistakes in matching up the function signatures.  You're also once again repeating the error of returning a pointer to a local variable that falls out of scope.

To upcast means to simply treat a derived type as its parent type, by referring it it through a base type pointer or reference, like so:

```
Base* ptr = new D1;
```

You don't need to `dynamic_cast` anything inside your clone() function.  I assume the intent was for you to use `dynamic_cast` from some external function (IE `main()`) to do a check that ensures that your `Base*` pointer in fact points to a `D1` object.

Comment: `Base* copy new Base(this);` doesn't call anything, but just leads to a syntax error. You perhaps meant `Base *copy = new Base(*this);`

Comment: Oops yes, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What is my problem

The author expects you to create an object from free store dynamically and return the pointer to that object. Although you'd have a derived type pointer, since it's up casting this would work as expected.

> I can't imagine how to return D1* object if we should override virtual Base* clone().

Look up a concept called *covariant return types* which exactly is about what you are asking.